# JavaFX animations are flickering

Tags: animation, javafx, flicker, artifacts

I have a window displaying a video stream with a twitter feed as an overlay.
When a new tweet is displayed, the current tweet animates out using a rotate animation and the next tweet is rotated into view. The animations are performed using a `RotateTransition`.

The app also switches between different cameras to display different streams. To give an indication of when the app switches to the next camera, I have a progressbar that fills using a `Timeline` object.

This works well, until I resize the window. The rotate animations start to flicker, along with the progressbars as they gradually fill.

As a test, I disabled the video stream, to see what's happening. The 'artifact' doesn't occur then and I can resize as much as I want. If I play the stream and don't resize, everything works well.

The video player is based on VLCJ, but the actual pixels are drawn on a `WritableImage` in an `Imageview`.

See the following images that illustrate the problem.

[image: Normal mode, no video playing]

[image: Bugged mode, while video playing]

At the bottom right you can see 2 different progress bars (a `ProgresBar` and a `ProgressIndicator`).

A part of the flickering result is still visible below the second image. It somehow stays visible, probably because the area doesn't get redrawn.

Any idea what makes the flickering happen? Is there anything I can do to fix or avoid this?

I tried some VM options in IntelliJ: `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=true -Dprism.forceGPU=true` to somehow enable hardware acceleration, but that doesn't seem to help.

Disabling the progressbar fill animation doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with some arcs and shapes that would flicker when its attributes / sizes were changed.

The solution to my problem was to make sure that the methods used to change the shapes were called from inside the JavaFX thread.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    arc.setStartAngle(30);
    arc.setLength(45);
}
```